# iTerm2 outputs random characters when the remote tmux exits abnormally

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I use tmux on my remote terminal. I found that when the remote terminal was disconnected abnormally (e.g., I just closed my laptop without exiting remote terminal normally), my terminal on iTerm will start to output random characters if I scroll my mouse, or click.

Any advice how to fix it?

Comment: Well, the only way works for me is, ssh to remote server and re-attach to tmux.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and found this answer which helped me: [Disable mouse reporting in a terminal session after tmux exits unexpectedly](https://superuser.com/questions/802698/disable-mouse-reporting-in-a-terminal-session-after-tmux-exits-unexpectedly)

To disable Mouse Reporting from bash, use this code:

```
printf '\e[?1000l'
```

Comment: OK. This can prevent random characters output. However, mouse scroll doesn't scroll the screen anymore.

Comment: @oujiafan, that's not the case for me. After `printf '\e[?1000l'` I can scroll just fine.