# Tmux (?) or something (some other client?) adds `^@` or whitespace characters

Tags: tmux, iterm2, iterm, mosh

I just wonder, sth adds `^@` or whitespace characters to my Tmux session. Tmux runs on another server, and I'm connected to it via Mosh. What could that be?

In one pane, it is lots of of `^@`, e.g. `^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@`, but one `^@` a time, maybe one or two per minute, with varying intervals.

This is a pane where some script is currently running:
[image: screenshot ctrl at char]

Or in another pane, no script is running, just the shell. Here for some reason, whitespaces are added, in similar time intervals:
[image: screenshot whitespace]

I assume it is some other client which is also currently still connected? (I probably have some other connections open on some other computers to this Tmux session.)

But why would another client do that?

Maybe there is a simple explanation. I will try to find out myself now… But just from these symptoms, what would you guess? I think it's the first time that I see this.

**Udate** There were 4 clients connected. I disconnected two of them, which means that there is only one other connected client now despite my local computer currently. And I still see that characters are being added. I'm afraid that the effect will go away when I disconnect that other client now, so I will leave it connected for now. I think I know where this is open, and I will check that computer tomorrow.

**Update** Actually I suspected the wrong computer. It was even on the same computer I'm currently using, but in iTerm, which I was just trying out again. Normally I just use Terminal. So could this be caused by iTerm? It correlates strongly that I see this now for the first time and I think I also use iTerm now for the first time in this specific setup (Mosh, Tmux). Also, I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1299247/iterm2-outputs-random-characters-when-the-remote-tmux-exits-abnormally) very related report/question (not 100% the same though: it's not random characters, it's always just `^@` or whitespace; also, iTerm is not even in the foreground, and it does not seem to be related to scroll events, although not 100% sure). Also, I now disconnected in iTerm and then reconnected, and so far, I don't see it anymore. But that other report mentioned sth about remote terminal disconnected abnormally. I'm not exactly sure what that means. When I put my computer to sleep and then open it again, it's still connected, as this is Mosh.

**Update**: I see it again. It is definitely iTerm.

**Update** Related is maybe also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161906/2954), which covers iTerm, Tmux and Mosh.